# Plots to illustrate results of linear mixed effect model - continued

Tags: r, lme4, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot similar to the one found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/98958/plots-to-illustrate-results-of-linear-mixed-effect-model

(for ease of reference, here is the code from that link:

```
library(nlme)
fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1|Subject)

newdat <- expand.grid(Sex=unique(Orthodont$Sex),
                  age=c(min(Orthodont$age),
                        max(Orthodont$age)))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Orthodont, aes(x=age, y=distance, colour=Sex)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(fm2), group=Subject, size="Subjects")) +
  geom_line(data=newdat, aes(y=predict(fm2, level=0, newdata=newdat), size="Population")) +
  scale_size_manual(name="Predictions", values=c("Subjects"=0.5, "Population"=3)) +
  theme_bw(base_size=22) 
print(p)
```

I'm using lme4, however, instead of nlme.  From my understanding, the 'predict' function in the code below is determining the predicted values at the population level.  However, I'm not sure how to mimic this in lme4.

I have stimuli crossed with participants.  Here is some example data:

```
 Subject Sex StimID StimSex Response
1        1   M      1       M       84
2        1   M      2       M       54
3        1   M      3       F       62
4        1   M      4       F       22
5        1   M      5       F       75
6        2   M      1       M       56
7        2   M      2       M       73
8        2   M      3       F       98
9        2   M      4       F       86
10       2   M      5       F       74
11       3   M      1       M       85
12       3   M      2       M       44
13       3   M      3       F       51
14       3   M      4       F       51
15       3   M      5       F       31
16       4   M      1       M       24
17       4   M      2       M       78
18       4   M      3       F       16
19       4   M      4       F       50
20       4   M      5       F       61
21       5   F      1       M       76
22       5   F      2       M       95
23       5   F      3       F       36
24       5   F      4       F       36
25       5   F      5       F       15
26       6   F      1       M       80
27       6   F      2       M       97
28       6   F      3       F       70
29       6   F      4       F        8
30       6   F      5       F       24
31       7   F      1       M       86
32       7   F      2       M       22
33       7   F      3       F       97
34       7   F      4       F       88
35       8   F      5       F       21
36       8   F      1       M        3
37       8   F      2       M       21
38       8   F      3       F        4
39       8   F      4       F       69
40       8   F      5       F       84
```

I am plotting stimuli sex on the x axis and response on the y axis. I would like individual lines for each participant (color coded by participant sex) and two thicker lines that show the population averages for male and female participants.  Here is the code I have:

```
lmer1<- lmer(Response~StimSex*Sex + (Sex|StimID) + (StimSex|Subject), data = dat)


p1<- ggplot(dat, aes(x=StimSex, y = Response, colour = Sex))+
  geom_point(size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(lmer1), group = Subject, size = "Subjects"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(lmer1), group = Sex, size = "Population Average"))+
  scale_size_manual(name="Predictions", values=c("Subjects"=0.5, "Population Average"=2))

p1
```

This creates the plot with individual subject lines, but I am not sure that the thick lines reflect the average for 'Sex'.  These are from the same data as the data that created the individual Subject lines - that is, I did not create new data (as in the example above) and use the population level predictions.  I'm just wanting to make sure that I am approaching this the right way.  I want the thicker lines to show me the average slope across all male and female participants, not a line connecting the average female participants' response to female stimuli to the average female participants' response to male stimuli (and the same for male participants) - I believe showing a line between the averages for each stimuli type could be accomplished without a multilevel model because it ignores different random slopes.

Any advice is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: 'How to ____ in R' questions are generally off topic here. They can be on topic on [SO] (this one should be, eg). If you can wait, we can migrate this for you.

Comment: Read `help("predict.merMod")`. You need the `re.form` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for migrating this question to stackoverflow - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Roland  Thank you! That works!